# Dynamic table along with value

Tags: php

JQUERY

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#aggiungi').live('click', function(){
            var thisRow = $(this).parent().parent();

            // clone and add data
            thisRow.clone(true).insertAfter(thisRow).data('is_clone',true);
            $(this).val("-");
            $(this).attr("id","remove");

            var nextRow = thisRow.next();
            nextRow.find('input:not(#aggiungi)').val("");

            if (thisRow.data('is_clone')){
                while(thisRow.data('is_clone')){
                    thisRow = thisRow.prev();
                }
            }else{
                nextRow.children(":first").remove();
            }

            currRowSpan = thisRow.children(":first").attr("rowspan");
            thisRow.children(":first").attr("rowspan", currRowSpan+1);
        });

        $('#remove').live('click', function(){
            var thisRow = $(this).parent().parent(),
                prevRow = thisRow.prev();

            if (thisRow.data('is_clone')){
                while(prevRow.data('is_clone')){
                    prevRow = prevRow.prev();
                }
            }else{
                prevRow = thisRow.next()
                                 .removeData('is_clone')
                                 .children(":first")
                                 .before(thisRow.children(":first"))
                                 .end();
            }

            currRowSpan = prevRow.children(":first").attr("rowspan");
            prevRow.children(":first").attr("rowspan", currRowSpan-1);
            thisRow.remove();
        });


    </script>
```

PHP

```
        <form action="grading.php" method="post">              
                              <table width-"100%" id="tableRealizzazione">
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th style="padding:12px;text-align:center;">Personale</th>
                                    <th style="padding:12px;text-align:center;">Percentage</th>
                                    <th style="padding:12px;text-align:center;">Marketing point</th>
                                    <th style="padding:12px;text-align:center;">Add/Remove</th>
                                </tr>'; 

    echo '<tr class="even">
                                          <td></td>
                                          <td style="padding:12px;"><input type="text" value="" id="Personale" name="Personale"></td>
                                          <td style="padding:12px;">
                                            <input type="text" id="from" name="from" size="5%"> -
                                            <input type="text" id="to" name="to" size="5%"> %
                                          </td>
                                          <td style="padding:12px;"><input type="text" class="totaliCostiGestione" id="marketpt" name="marketpt"></td>
                                          <td style="padding:12px;"><input type="text" name="programid" value ="34" size="10%"></td>
                                          <td style="padding:12px;"><input type="button" value="+" id="aggiungi"/></td>';         
                                   echo '</tr>';
 echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>';                      
                 echo '</table>
               </form>
```

When I fill the values of all text boxes and click submit, it prints only the last row and the the last row with value 34 not repeating for all the rest rows.

Here is my code in Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gansai/PA9JF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have to make arrays from your form:

eg:

```
<input type="text" id="from" name="from[]" size="5%"> -
```

to clone values you have to add:

```
newRow = thisRow.clone(true).insertAfter(thisRow).data('is_clone',true);
$(newRow+"[name^=programid]").val($(thisRow+"[name^=programid]").val());
```

Like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DjddU/)

then in PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['marketpt'] as $num => $val){
    $Personale = $_POST[$num]['Personale'];
    $from = $_POST[$num]['from'];
    $to = $_POST[$num]['to'];
    $marketpt = $_POST[$num]['marketpt'];
    $programid = $_POST[$num]['programid'];
    // process variables, eg: insert in database
}
```

Comment: `clone()` does not copy the values, you have to add script to do that

Comment: Thank You for your kind help, but wen I submit it was showing array

Comment: Yes, as it should be, loop in each. I've modified my answer. If you don't make array you won't be able to get all values.

Comment: And when I delete with '-' icon the rows are getting disturbed, Have you seen that

Comment: there was something mistake character after this line  $(this).attr("id","remove");
        a

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again,  The rows aren't printing when I submit to grading.php and when I click icon '-' the rows are getting disturbed

Comment: It shows these errors When I click submit Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\grading.php on line 5 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\grading.php on line 6  Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\grading.php on line 7  Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\grading.php on line 8

Comment: That is your PHP part. You have to learn how to manipulate PHP. From my Oppinion I've answered to your question. If you believe your question was solved consider accepting one answer, if you have any more questions please use the `Ask Question` button.

Comment: The php part i solved, there need to be done the last thing in this section i.e., when I click '+' icon, I need only the programid value to be repeated and the rest with empty text boxes. But right now It is repeating the values for all the 4 textboxes

Comment: Can we have serial no's incrementing

Comment: Serial No column before Personale column

Comment: I don't see any Serial No. Please post a new question for that

Comment: Serial No's on creating dynamic rows and columns with the same question jsfiddle.net/fxxYe - you helped us before

Comment: Yes there was no serial no before, but can we add serial no (incrementing) 1,2, 3 in the jquery you provided us

Comment: Jquery isn't working in my pages, so we need to download jquery1.8.2 version as I have Jquery 1.7.1

Comment: Updation - When I get all the values and display them back to input fields, I am getting add button for all the rows, but I need add button for the last row. http://jsfiddle.net/gansai/w8HGQ/ [ I think PHP scripting willn't work in Fiddle]. Iam sending you in codepad too - http://codepad.org/5GEucEYm. I think there was a problem in jquery code

Comment: HI Mihai Iorga -  jsfiddle.net/IorgaMihai/p5QwC -  Can we add add/remove function to the same button instead remove before row. It was a creating a problem in the jquery as I hope this is the code I got from you. Could you help me with this jquery